# After updating Android stuido project is not running gives errror

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kapt

After updating android studio I am unable to run Android project, it gives compile time error, I am unable to run my project

Android studio version=Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Java version =compile=target=java gradle =version 17

Plugins added in project level

```
plugins{
      id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
      id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
      id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false 
}
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
       > Compilation error. See log for more details
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)

        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
```

Comment: Can you run your gradle command with `--stacktrace` option?

Comment: Yes I already run with --stacktrace option but still it gives the same error,  it fails at this app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin

Comment: Check the libraries which are usingkapt. Check [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html) to migrate Android Studio Gradle plugin from 7 to 8